# Dynamically load a component inside a Material MatDialog

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Can anyone provide an example of how to dynamically load a component into a Material MatDialog?

What I would like to do is this: I will provide the MatDialog configuration data with a  component Type which the dialog would then create an instance of and place inside it's mat-dialog-content area.

It appears I would need to use some combination of ng-template and viewContainerRef, but I do not know how to instantiate the provided component Type and insert into the desired area.

A simple example:

```
    <h2 mat-dialog-title>MyTitle</h2>
    <mat-dialog-content>
     <---- dynamically loaded component would be inserted here ---->
    </mat-dialog-content>

    <mat-dialog-actions>
      <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
      <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Save</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There are different options:

**1)** Built-in structural directive **ngComponentOutlet**

```html
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="data.component"></ng-container>
```

**[Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/uhR7qzifwhr3QH9fNOMv?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

**2)** Using angular material cdk. More precisely you can use `PortalModule` from secondary entry point `@angular/cdk/portal`

**dialog.component.ts**

```ts
import { ComponentPortal } from '@angular/cdk/portal';

@Component({...})
export class DialogDialog {

  portal: ComponentPortal<any>;

  constructor(...
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.portal = new ComponentPortal(this.data.component);
  }
```

**dialog.component.html**

```ts
<ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="portal"></ng-template>
```

**[Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/OP87U87X2gR7U4ZmsxN3?open=app%2Fdialog.component.html)**

**3)** Using Angular low-level API

**dialog.component.ts**

```ts
@Component({...})
export class DialogDialog {

  @ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) vcRef: ViewContainerRef;

  componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(
    ...
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.data.component);
    this.componentRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory);
  }


  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.componentRef) {
      this.componentRef.destroy();
    }
  }  
}
```

**dialog.component.html**

```ts
<ng-template #target></ng-template>
```

**[Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/9giHmJ8bzMa8tBcZAm5t?open=app%2Fdialog.component.html)**

Comment: Option 3 worked best for me since I needed access to the component instance.  Thanks much!

Comment: @yurzui can we pass a template string to a ComponentPortal ? or does it always have to a ComponentType.

Comment: option number 3 really helped me achieving the wanted behavior !

Comment: @yurzui These look really useful. Unfortunately, none of the provided examples now run.

Comment: @CraigShearer Sorry for that. I've just updated all examples

Comment: @yurzui what about if the content is form and the actions have to be connected with form

Comment: @yurzui I have tried all 3 solutions, and with all 3 the data that is bound to the component that I pass to the dialog show up as "undefined".  I'm not sure what Im doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: this not only answers the question but also shows different ways to create dynamic component. Thanks

Comment: @yurzui can you please share an example on how to pass @@Input values of dynamic component

Comment: I've been trying for hours to pass data to the inserted component with no luck.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Louis Can you please create a simple reproducible example of what you're trying to achieve in stackblitz?

Comment: Thanks! Here is one of your examples copied with what I've been trying to do. Without the injector it works as expected.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-9-dynamic-modal-content-w-data?file=src/app/dialog.component.ts

Comment: @Louis You can take a look at this updated version https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-9-dynamic-modal-content-w-data-otdb4p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog.component.html

Comment: I totally see what I was doing wrong. If you are ever in Atlanta I will buy you whatever you drink! This is so much easier than I was making it. Thanks! Implemented It Already And It WORKS!

Comment: Option 3 doesn't work with angular 14.

Answer (score -4):

The actual modal component .ts:
(note that the modal component's `html` is where you will write your code above)

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-modal',
    templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CreateFirmComponent>,
                @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any)
                 {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onConfirm() {
        this.dialogRef.close(true);
    }

    onCancel(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close(false);
    }

}
```

And the component from where you call the Modal:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material';
import {ModalComponent} from './modal-component';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-list',
    templateUrl: './list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {


    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {
    }




    openDialog(): void {
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, {
            width: '500px'
        });

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            // result is what you get after you close the Modal
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't believe this answers my problem.  The content inside the <mat-dialog-content> tags is determined at run time.  So, in my mind, your ModalComponent would then need to inspect the MAT_DIALOG_DATA, which will specify the component TYPE to create, creates that component and inserts that created component inside the <mat-dialog-content> tags.