# Best practice in angular, material to reuse component in dialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my business application I have the requirement to select records in a list, update the record data, select next item in list, and so on.

**Use Case 1**
Select item in list, open a dialog, manipulate data there and then return to list

**Use Case 2**
Navigate to page (via router), manipulate data there, navigate further from there

So what I want to **avoid is to implement my business component twice**. First time to make it work with the dialog and second time to make it behave like a "normal" component e.g. with prefetching data by resolver etc.

Anybody can tell me what is the best practice to do this in angular? **Use component with router and open it in a dialog as well**

I've found this one here==>
[Dynamically load a component inside a Material MatDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723439/dynamically-load-a-component-inside-a-material-matdialog)

But e.g. this doesn't answer how to deal with prefetching (resolvers). From what I know dialogs are not using route resolvers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using Angular Material you can reuse your business component by adding the `@Optional()` decorator to `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)`. So your reusable component looks somewhat like:

```
export class MyBusinessComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;
  constructor(
   @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private dialogData: any,
   private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.data = dialogData ? dialogData : null;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (dialogData) {
      this.data = dialogData
    } else {
      this.data = this._route.snapshot.data
    }
  }
}
```

When you want to use the component as a dialog you put:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PriceBreakupSectionComponent, { data: { somedata: 'somevalue' } })
```

Comment: you are awesome

Comment: Thank you @JohnWillson