# Dynamic Content Projection Angular MatDialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-dialog, angular-content-projection

Imagine a project structure like this:

```
app
--lazyModA
----ATable
--lazyModB
----BTable
--shared
----DialogWithTables
```

We need to have a MatDialog in both lazyModA and lazyModB which are both lazy loaded which is able to display the MatTables ATable or BTable in the respective case. [In practise I will have at least 5 of those modules and tables]

Apart from the different Table the dialogs are exactly the same, which is why I would like to put it into the shared module.
But here lies the problem. If I hardcode the tables in the template of DialogWithTables it would always load all my lazy modules once the Dialog opens anywhere.

The idea was to use [ContentProjection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection) but since we are instantiating the Dialog in Typescript that seams to be out of the picture.

I have tried to pass the content via the MAT_DIALOG_DATA Injection Token like this:

```js
this.dialog.open(DialogWithTables,
  {data: {content:'<app-a-table [dataSource]="dataSource"></app-a-table>'}
  }
)
```

and different variations on the syntax but nothing seems to work as intended.
I would really like to do this the clean way and not define seperate dialogs for each module.

My compromise which I am currently programming would be to define seperate dialogs but having them use the traditional content projection.

```html
<app-dialog-with-tables>
  <app-a-table [dataSource]="dataSource"></app-a-table>
</app-dialog-with-tables>
```

But this still feels unsatisfying to me. Any help tricks or suggestion is welcome :)

---UPDATE---

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723439/dynamically-load-a-component-inside-a-material-matdialog?rq=1) which recommended using the [*ngComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) which seems to be working just fine. Now I am just struggling to get my dataSource into the mix.